# How to capture a timestamp in MySql programmatically?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am new to MySQL and databases in general so I am sorry if this is a novice question.  I am creating a MySQL database with a users table.  One of the columns is `UserAccept` and the other is `UserAcceptWhen`.  When they log in to the program, which is built using C#, they have to accept a user agreement first.  If they click Accept, then then get in, but the question is about updating the table.  Once they click Accept, `UserAccept` will change from 0 to 1, but how can I then have `UserAcceptWhen` update with the current date and time?  Also, can I lock that column from changing, unless the `UserAccept` column changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Matt Clark said you can use the MySQL NOW() function to store the current time value. 
One small addendum is to consider using trigger for updating UserAcceptWhen when UserAccept changes.
Something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER UserAcceptedNOW BEFORE UPDATE ON user
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF (NEW.UserAccepted = 1) THEN
      SET NEW.UserAcceptedWhen = NOW();
    END IF;  
  END
//
```

Don't forget to set UserAcceptWhen to Timestamp type.

For the second question: afaik you can't lock a column for change.

Normally it is better afaik to use the logic outside of the db (it will be easier to dump the db) but it is a sollution too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great function in MySQL called `NOW()` which returns the time and date.

```
UPDATE table SET UserAcceptWhen = NOW() WHERE id = 1;
```